# Extracting a value from an ets:lookup() - Erlang

Tags: function, erlang, tuples, extract, ets

I have a ets table formatted as below

```
ets:new(players, [set,named_table])
```

The data that is put into the table is a players name and their age.

It is in the format of [{Name,Age}]

I made a function to try get a players age and age only.

```
getPlayerAge(PlayerName)->
  Player = ets:lookup(players,PlayerName),
  [{_,Age}] = Player,
  Age.
```

I am getting a badmatch error and honestly I am confused as hell.

Can this be done or am I way off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the exact error is this one:

```
{badmatch, []}
```

That is, the value you got from `ets:lookup` is `[]`, the empty list, and that doesn't match the pattern `[{_,Age}]`.  `ets:lookup` returns an empty list if it doesn't find an element with the given key.  You could check that the table actually contains what you expect it to contain by calling `ets:tab2list(players)` and inspecting the return value.

Comment: Yeah so I have done that and the return value is [{{player,age}}]

Comment: @Deckster711 Ah, the table element is wrapped in an extra tuple. What does your `ets:insert` look like?